# What missingness mechanism do I have if I have blocks of rows with missing data?

Tags: r, time-series, dataset, missing-data

Suppose I have a time series of daily resolution for the year 2000. This dataset details different climate variables from humidity, precipitation, temperature, etc.

I would like to check for the missingness mechanism of this. But before I do that, something concerns me.

There are blocks of rows that have missing data, like all variables are NA. Some blocks of 3, some as big as 20.

I ran this with R in BaylorEdPsych. This question at StackOverflow is how I did it, along with an answer for it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954856/littles-mcar-test-in-r-bayloredpsych-package-does-not-work/43958050#43958050

What missingness mechanism is this? (Please let it not be MNAR, please not MNAR, for the love of everything good and holy please let it not be MNAR)

Here's the file if you guys need a visual.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8hGFkkZ5DlfZFl4MGxXY1Y2dlE

Thanks to anyone who replies.